# Discord bot problems

Tags: python, bots, discord

I started making a discord bot but unfortunately, right at the beginning, I encountered a problem. Here is my code, which I have copied from a discord bot tutorial:

```
import discord


TOKEN = 'MYTOKEN'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event()
async def on_ready():
    print(client.user + " says hi")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

But when I run it I get back this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mateveres/PycharmProjects/xdddd/faszom.py", line 8, in <module>
    @client.event()
TypeError: event() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'coro'
```

Comment: Include Python version and installed Python dependencies in your question (`python3 -V` and `python3 -m pip freeze`)

Comment: Thank you! My python version is Python 3.7.0 and I am using discord.py 1.3.3.

Comment: `@client.event` instead of `@client.event()`

Answer (score 3):

Replace `client.event()` with `client.event`. See the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.event).

```py
import discord


TOKEN = 'MYTOKEN'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.user + " says hi")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

From looking at my previous code for my own project, I notice that my client event doesnt have parenthesis. Maybe this is what is creating your error?

For example,

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f"{member} has joined the server... What a scoundrel")
```

My own on_ready method looks like this

```
@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print("Code init.... Done!")
```

Other than that, i'd say you're well on your way to starting up your first bot.

Answer (score 1):

Simple! Just remove the parenthesis.
Like this:

```py
@client.event
```

and not

```py
@client.event()
```